# MeCabを用いたSinatraアプリをHerokuにデプロイする方法をご教示ください。

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, heroku, mecab, sinatra

[類似の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/40200/heroku%E3%81%ABmecab%E3%82%92%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)がありましたが、回答がありませんでしたので質問させていただきます。

タイトルの通り、MeCabを用いたSinatraアプリをHerokuにデプロイしようとしています。

## 環境

ローカルPC：Mac OSX

```
$heroku -v
heroku/7.6.0 darwin-x64 node-v10.6.0 # homebrewで入れました

$ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]

$gem list | grep sinatra
sinatra (2.0.3, 2.0.2)

$mecab -v
mecab of 0.996 # homebrewで入れました
```

herokuのOS:Ubuntu

```
$heroku run bash
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS"
```

## 私のGemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "sinatra"
gem "sinatra-contrib"
gem "mecab", "0.996"
gem "natto"
gem "pry"
```

## heroku buildpacks

```
$heroku buildpacks
=== mecab-on-sinatra Buildpack URLs
1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
2. https://github.com/diasks2/heroku-buildpack-mecab.git
```

## エラー

```
extconf.rb:12:in ``': No such file or directory - mecab-config (Errno::ENOENT)
    from extconf.rb:12:in `<main>'
An error occurred while installing mecab (0.996), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mecab -v '0.996'` succeeds before bundling.

   In Gemfile:
     mecab
```

## 試したこと

```
$ heroku run bash
```

でherokuのbashに入って`gem install mecab -v '0.996'`しようとしたところパーミッションがなく、
sudoをつけたらsudoコマンドがnot foundでした…。

どうすればこれらを解決してアプリをデプロイできるでしょうか。ご教示ください。

Answer (score 1):

長文失礼します。

質問者さんの環境とは異なりますが、以下の組み合わせが最小構成だと思われれます。ご参考になれば。

### ファイル構成

```
mecab_on_heroku   // 任意のディレクトリ名
  ├── .gitignore
  ├── Gemfile
  ├── Gemfile.lock
  ├── Procfile
  └── app.rb
```

#### .gitignore

```
/vendor
```

#### Gemfile

```
ruby "2.3.7"
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'mecab', '0.996'
```

#### Procfile

```
web: ruby app.rb
```

#### app.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'mecab'

get '/' do
  str = "我々宇宙人は地球を侵略しに来ました。"
  tagger = MeCab::Tagger.new
  "#{tagger.parse(str)}"
end
```

Gemfile.lock は Gemfile を保存してから以下のコマンドを実行すると作成されます。

#### Gemfile.lock 生成のためのコマンド実行

```
$ bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

### heroku のデプロイ

```
$ cd mecab_on_heroku  # 任意の作業ディレクトリ
$ heroku create -a heroku_app_name --buildpack \
    https://github.com/diasks2/heroku-buildpack-mecab.git
$ heroku config:set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/vendor/mecab/lib
```

上記 5つのファイルを作成したのち、下記のコマンドを実行してデプロイします。

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "first commit."
$ git push heroku master
```

### 動作確認

以下のコマンドを実行すると、自動でデフォルトブラウザが開いて Sinatra アプリにアクセスします。

```
$ heroku open
```

[heroku](/questions/tagged/heroku) [sinatra](/questions/tagged/sinatra) [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) [mecab](/questions/tagged/mecab)

Comment: ご丁寧な回答をありがとうございます。

質問でも述べました通り私はruby 2.4.0を使って失敗しており、
またLD_LIBRARY_PATHという環境変数は[こちら](https://qiita.com/shouta-dev/items/cd538a77f2b729333025)にしたがって設定していました。

hidao様のご指摘の通りにこれらの点を修正し、
1) Gemfileにruby version '2.3.7' を指定 
2) LD_LIBRARY_PATH を /app/vendor/mecab/libとする
と、無事デプロイできました。

改めまして、ありがとうございました。

Comment: また、おそらく nattoを使うとApplication Errorになることが発覚しました…。